# syntax for ruby using activerecord & sinatra (not using rails)

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a reference to a Model object called Admin which has a field called id.   The value gets printed out in the puts line.  I now need to pass in that ID into an ActiveRecord call to create another object (where it serves as foreign key) as follows but it throws an exception copied below (the admin.id does not get picked up in the Bill.create call):

```
admin = Admin.find_by(email:email)
puts "admin id #{admin.id}"  # this gets printed with correct value  
bill = Bill.create(admin_id: admin.id, body: body)
```

**Exception:**

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:59:in `rescue in _assign_attribute': unknown attribute 'admin_id' for Bill. (ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:564:in `init_attributes'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
        from test.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

**My ActiveRecord migration file for the Bills model**:

```
 def up
     create_table :bills do |t|
         t.integer :admin_id
         t.text :body
     end
    add_foreign_key :bills, :admins
  end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no `admin_id` on your `bills` table, so you haven't run your migration in its current state.

You may need to run migrations...

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

or *re-run* your migration if you've modified it after previously running it. Changing a migration doesn't affect the actual database in any way unless you forcibly re-run that migration. If this is the last migration, you can do:

```
$ rake db:redo
```

If it's not the last migration, you can supply a `STEP` argument to tell `rake` how many migrations downwards it should go.

Comment: @user3813256 I'm trying to help you. Do you have constructive feedback?

Comment: apologies if you did not remove my first comment and downvoted my question- I thought you removed my comment and downvoted my question when I simply made a mistake.  Perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: @user3813256 I deleted my entire first answer, as it was no longer relevant, after you fixed your typo. Even if I didn't delete my answer, I would have deleted your comment, as your edit made it obsolete. Comments on this site are *temporary* and can be deleted at any time, please remember this. Please also remember that receiving a downvote is absolutely not an excuse to be abusive to other users, especially since you have no idea who is actually downvoting you.

Comment: can we simply call a truce :)  I wish you the best.  Thank you for answering on both cases.  I resolved the issue earlier (same as you mentioned).